# convert original URL to friendly URL and display it in browser's address bar

Tags: php, .htaccess

In my website there is a link to registered tutors. That link is something like this

```
http://www.lankainstitute.com/profiles/centers/index.php?code=1203&institute=Montana+Higher+Educational+Institute#page=art-section
```

So I need to rewrite this link and after rewrite it want to display in my browser's address bar something like this:

```
www.lankainstitute.com/1203/Montana-Higher-Educational-Institute
```

Can anybody tell me is it possible to rewrite above original URL to my expected URL and can display it in address bar?

Thank you..

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Google `RewriteRule`

Comment: @tharanga nuwan kumara, see my answer for example

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this by adding a line in your .htaccess file.

Comment: can you explain it with en example? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the server (Apache, ISS) there are tool to do so. Like in Apache mod_rewrite, look for some sample rewrite rules.

for example

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
Alias /myapp /opt/myapp-1.2.3
<Directory /opt/myapp-1.2.3>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /myapp/
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$  welcome.html 
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

[learn more](http://blog.eprakash.info/2012/01/10-useful-ways-to-rewrite-url-using.html) to use htaccess for url rewriting

Well, in this case, you can simply do this:

`http://www.lankainstitute.com/profiles/centers/index.php?code=1203&institute=Montana+Higher+Educational+Institute#page=art-section` to `www.lankainstitute.com/1203/Montana-Higher-Educational-Institute`

Code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?code=$1&institute=$2
```

Add this code in your `.htaccess` file

Comment: I added your code to my .htaccess file.. but nothing happen and display ugly url for far in my address bar

Comment: ofcourse.. the url doesn't change... after adding that code try hitting : `www.lankainstitute.com/1203/Montana-Higher-Educational-Institute` should display the same page as : `http://www.lankainstitute.com/profiles/centers/index.php?code=1203&institute=Montana+Higher+Educational+Institute#page=art-section`

Comment: I checked then I load my main index page without styles.. But I want to load index page that in 'center' sub folder. and need to change url in address bar also..

Comment: look, you're now talking about entire problem out of this questoin, open another question for that. And, Did that solve? is `www.lankainstitute.com/1203/Montana-Higher-Educational-Institute` displaying same page as `http://www.lankainstitute.com/profiles/centers/index.php?code=1203&institute=Mo‌​ntana+Higher+Educational+Institute#page=art-section` ?? If yes, try to learn what that code is from the link I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

Use your .htaccess file.
Look into **RewriteEngine**